# How to show the relational data from mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am calling a get request to a relational data from mongodb. I'm accessing my Scheduled Match with Team Data linked but I don't know how to display the data from the Team data(linked data). Here is my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const abortController = new AbortController();
        const signal = abortController.signal;

        const getScheduledMatch = async () => {
            try {
                const schedules = await fetchContext.authAxios.get(
                    '/facilitator/scheduled-match',
                    {
                        signal: signal,
                    }
                );
                // console.log(schedules.data.scheduleMatch);
                setScheduledMatch(schedules.data.scheduleMatch);
                return function cleanup() {
                    abortController.abort();
                };
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
            return function cleanup() {
                abortController.abort();
            };
        };
        getScheduledMatch();
    }, [fetchContext]);
            <Grid>
                {scheduledMatch.map((match) => (
                    <Grid key={match._id}>
                        <Typography variant="h6">Scheduled Match</Typography>
                        <Typography variant="h6">{`Date and Time: ${match.date}`}</Typography>
                        <Typography variant="h6">{`Game: ${match.gameEvent}`}</Typography>
                        <Typography variant="h6">Team A</Typography>
                        {match.teamOne.map((team) => (
                            <Grid key={team._id}>
                                <Typography variant="h6">{`Team Name: ${team.teamName}`}</Typography>
                                <Typography variant="h6">Players</Typography>
                            </Grid>
                        ))}
                    </Grid>
                ))}
            </Grid>
```

I am having an error teamOne.map is not a function. This is my schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const scheduleSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        user: {
            type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
        },
        date: {
            type: Date,
            required: true,
        },
        teamOne: {
            type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'teams',
        },
        teamTwo: {
            type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'teams',
        },
        gameEvent: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('schedule', scheduleSchema);
```

There is no error until:

```
<Typography variant="h6">Team A</Typography>
```

Comment: In the schema the `teamOne` is an object so it does not have `.map` function. You treat it as an array, why? Intead of `{match.teamOne.map((team) ...` add two grids like so `<Grid key={match.teamOne._id}>...</Grid>` and `<Grid key={match.teamTwo._id}>...</Grid>`

Comment: @Molda, it is a relational data, so those ObjectId it's referring to a team data ids. So I can map the team data referring to that ObjectId. The problem is, I can't display the team data with that ObjectId

Comment: Based on the schema i assume that when you query mongo you use something like `Schedule.find().populate('teamOne').populate('teamTwo')` this will return an array of scheduled matches each something like this `{ user: .., ..., teamOne: { _id: 'sdas', teamName: 'blabla', <some other team props>}, teamTwo: { <similar to teamOne> }, ... }` As i said in above comment, based on your schema teamOne and teamTwo are objects and you can't use `.map(..)` because they are not an array.

Comment: If teamOne/Two should be an array you need to define it a such using an array like this `teamOne: [{  type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'teams' }]`

Comment: @Molda, yes that is the query that I use. But how to access those data without changing it to an array? Thank you for your advice mate.

Comment: when I console.log i get:                                                                                                  `0:
createdAt: "2021-03-23T11:08:45.699Z"
date: "2021-03-23T11:08:22.626Z"
gameEvent: "basketball"
teamOne: Array(1)
0: "6054a008011bb34a601c4126"
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
teamTwo: Array(1)
0: "6054a8d63fec5c24389624ac"
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
updatedAt: "2021-03-23T11:08:45.699Z"
user: "60489c407de3db57bc73468a"
__v: 0
_id: "6059cc3d4e45322ee459a8f4"`

Comment: @Molda Thank you mate, it got it now. You can post your answer bro.